# How to make menu bar fixed so it doesn't move when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have three issues:

1. I want my menu links to 'bold' when I hover on them, but it makes the items to the right move over slightly when I do, how can I stop them from moving?
2. The dropdown menu on "Two", how do I make it so the items appear directly lined up beneath "Two" , with appropriate spacing, and with an equal width background despite the two items not being the same amount of characters?
3. What can I do to make the menu bar fixed so that when I scroll down, it remains visible at the top of the page? I tried add "position: fixed" but that just messes it all up..

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
                </ul></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="middle"></div>     
    <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I couldn't figure out how to paste css in here without it getting all garbled up so here's a link to the stylesheet: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14754850/stylesheet.css

Comment: It's not a dumb question.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: These aren't dumb questions, but these are indeed questions, as in plural. Please open multiple question posts for different questions, to keep everything organized, don't ask a multitude of questions at once :)

Comment: To make your question "more persistent" (instead of storing source code in your dropbox) you can create a fiddle, where other users can test your code. You can insert all your HTML, CSS and JavaScript there. This time I created one for you. :) http://jsfiddle.net/y7SAX/

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that next time!

Answer (score 3):

Here are the answers to your two first problems:

**1)**

```
#menu ul li {
   ...
   width: 90px; /* Give items fixed size */
}
```

**2)**

```
#menu ul li ul li {
   background-color: #2d2d2d; /* Add background */ 
}

#menu ul li ul li:last-child {
   padding-bottom: 10px; /* Dirty fix for last menu item */
}
```

**Added:**

```
#menu ul li ul li a {
   padding-bottom: 0px; /* Makes drop down items more compact */
}

#menu ul li a { 
   ...
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; /* Give menu headers some spacing */
   ... 
} 

#menu ul {
   padding: 0; /* Fix left space */
}
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/uYTnf/3/

Comment: thanks, but when i make the changes in coda (even if i copy paste the entire thing) the drop down items don't line up with "two" like they do in your fiddle.. despite it being the exact same code? Any idea why? Screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14754850/Screen%20shot%202012-11-20%20at%207.47.54%20PM.jpg

Comment: I can also see that. Added a few things to the answer.

Comment: Who knew making a simple menu would be so complicated :) Thanks it works now, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: No problem. There might be better ways to do this but we won't know until someone makes an edit:)

Answer (score 1):

Start with keeping the menu div out of the wrap div. That way you don't have any weird stuff going on with position: fixed.

1. Unfortunately, with width: auto you can't control the "pushing" that you see. You'll want to give the list items a fixed with (whether a percentage or pixel value). Percentage is preferred as it allows for responsive design.
2. Make sure the background color is applied to the ul element and not the li element. Also, use text-align: center to keep them nice and centered.
3. Position: fixed is correct! Just make sure to set top: 0 and left: 0 so that the bar doesn't do anything funky on different browsers. Also, you have padding on the top and bottom of your main container that is keeping the bar from being totally at the top.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/y7SAX/3/) a fiddle with the `#menu li:hover ul` changed and `#menu ul li ul li` added.

Comment: When I add     position: fixed; top: 0px; (i left out left: 0px; because that makes it worse) my menu bar ends up like this with Links stuck at the bottom of the bar, and the right side half of the bar missing: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14754850/Screen%20shot%202012-11-20%20at%209.53.48%20PM.jpg

Comment: Yes, there's a little more that needs to be changed. You'll find those changes in the fiddle I posted.

I'd recommend finding a website with a navbar that you like, inspect that navbar and analyze the way they structure and style it. There are a lot of similarities in the design among navbars. bootstrap.org may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this will help here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/squinny/tJZ25/1/

on the ul li  i just set the with to width: 100px;

```
    #menu ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;

     }
```